# Spring data mongodb - empty result while trying aggregate and project

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am having a bit of trouble with projecting and paging with mongooperations. I always get empty result. The query criteria working fine without aggregation. I tryed the same code without paging(skip&limit) and without sort but I still get the empty result.

My code:

```
public List<ProfileBasic> findAllActiveUsersByGenderAndAgeBetweenProjectedPage(Gender gender, int fromAge, int toAge, int pageSize, int page) {

        Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("gender").is(gender).and("confirmed").is(true)
                .and("dateOfBirth").lte(LocalDate.now().minusYears(fromAge))
                .gte(LocalDate.now().minusYears(toAge));
        MatchOperation match = Aggregation.match(criteria);
        ProjectionOperation  project = Aggregation.project()
                .and("id").as("id")
                .and("name").as("name")
                .and("lastName").as("lastName")
                .and("gender").as("gender")
                .and("dateOfBirth").as("dateOfBirth")
                .and("lastVisit").as("lastVisit");
        SkipOperation skip = new SkipOperation(pageSize*(page-1));
        LimitOperation limit = new LimitOperation(pageSize);
        SortOperation sort = new SortOperation(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "lastVisit"));
        Aggregation aggregate = Aggregation.newAggregation(project, match, skip, limit, sort);
        return operations.aggregate(aggregate, User.class, ProfileBasic.class).getMappedResults();
    }
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

When we do Aggregation in MongoDB data is processed in stages and the output of one stage is provided as input to the next stage.

In my code first stage was project and not match(query):

```
Aggregation aggregate = Aggregation.newAggregation(project, match, skip, limit, sort);
```

Thats why it didn't work.

I changed it to:

```
Aggregation aggregate = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, skip, limit, project, sort);
```

And now it works fine.